# Unexpected results when pausing and resuming crawls

Tags: python, scrapy

I have been testing [pausing and resuming crawls](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html) with [a spider from the tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests).

The spider -

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
                'author': quote.css('span small::text').get(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
            }

        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

### Test 1: Full uninterrupted crawl and overwrite any existing file `-O`

```
scrapy crawl quotes -s JOBDIR=crawls -O quotes.json
```

Results : `quotes.json` contains an array of 100 sets of quotes (all 10 pages) as expected

### Test 2: Repeat full uninterrupted crawl and overwrite any existing file `-O`

```
scrapy crawl quotes -s JOBDIR=crawls -O quotes.json
```

Result : `quotes.json` was overwitten with an array of 10 sets of quotes from http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/

Question: I would expect scrapy to know http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/ was already scraped. Why does it scrape the same URL again?

### Test 3: Delete output file and crawl directory, append new content to any existing file. `-o` and interrupt crawl with `CTRL-C`

```
scrapy crawl quotes -s JOBDIR=crawls -o quotes.json
[CTRL-C]
```

Results : `quotes.json` contains an array of 40 sets of quotes (first 4 pages)

### Test 4: Resume crawl with from Test 3 and append new content to any existing file. `-o`

```
scrapy crawl quotes -s JOBDIR=crawls -o quotes.json
```

Results :  `quotes.json` is now currupted with invalid JSON and contains about 110 sets of quotes

Question: Why does this happen? Is there a way to resume the crawl and build a correct output file?

Comment: Did you stop crawler gracefully (single CTRL+C) or not (double CTRL+C)?

Comment: @Georgiy I stopped the crawl gracefully with single CTRL+C